# RESTful way of returning a list of same objects

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I can't find this anywhere so my question is simple, let's say I have an endpoint like this:
GET /employees
Should the return object be:

```
[ 
   {id : 1, name: someName},
   {id : 2, name: someName}
]
```

Or is it better to have a wrapper object:

```
{
  employees: 
  [ 
     {id : 1, name: someName},
     {id : 2, name: someName}
  ]
}
```

Honestly I see no reason to have a wrapper when I'm returning a list of employees, however I've seen it in some places, so which is better?

Answer (score 0):

It's up to your business case. The second is preferred and is will be easier to scale if you need to add day "managers" further down the line.